# Alfresco: how get child of a child with javascript (and FTL)

Tags: alfresco, freemarker

I have a performance time problem with a custom webscript that I'm doing.

The webscript only search a node by uuid and return a JSON with some properties of the children of this node, and return the number of the subchilds of them too.

I do this in my js:

```
function main()
{
var node = [];
node = search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/"+args["uuid"]);
model.childResults = node.children;
} main();
```

And on my FTL I do this:

```
<#macro parseChild objectModel>
<#assign loop = 0 />
<#list objectModel as child>
    <#if (loop > 0) >, </#if>
    {
      "ID" : "${child.id}",
        "PROP_NAME" : "${child.properties["name"]}",
        <#if child.properties["cf:author"]?exists>
           "AUTHOR" : "${child.properties["cf:author"]}",
        </#if>
        <#if child.properties["cf:data_cf"]?exists>
           "PROP_CREATED" : "${xmldate(child.properties["cf:date_cf"]?datetime)}",
        </#if>
        "TYPE" : "${child.type}",
             "NUMBER_CHILDS" : ${child.children?size}

    <#assign loop = loop + 1 />
    }
</#list>
```

```
<#if (childResults?size > 0)>
{
"nodes" : 
[ 
    <@parseChild childResults/>
]
}
<#else>
Empty
</#if>
```

The problem is... I have over 200 folders on the node, and each one have 30 or 40 subfolders too. And when I do child.children?size the webscript takes a lot of time.

Are there any quickly way to know the number of childs on this 200 folders? child.children takes too long.

If this methos don't exists, I have another possibility. Returns only a parameter that gives me if each of this 200 folders have at least one children. For this, I only need to obtain a children of each one. How can I do this? What method can I apply to each child to obtain the first child or know if this child have a child?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Freemarker hint (maybe that was not available in the Freemarker version you have been using when posting the question): You can use the [sep-directive](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#autoid_96) instead of the mechanism using the `loop` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Alfresco-API documentation of findNode](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-findNode.html), you are dealing with instances of [ScriptNode](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/references/API-JS-ScriptNode.html).

You can use `child.hasChildren` to determine whether a ScriptNode has at least one child. So you could do something like this:

```
<#macro parseChild objectModel>
  <#list objectModel as child>
    {
      "ID" : "${child.id}",
      "PROP_NAME" : "${child.properties["name"]}",
      <#if child.properties["cf:author"]?exists>
         "AUTHOR" : "${child.properties["cf:author"]}",
      </#if>
      <#if child.properties["cf:data_cf"]?exists>
         "PROP_CREATED" : "${xmldate(child.properties["cf:date_cf"]?datetime)}",
      </#if>
      "TYPE" : "${child.type}",
      "HAS_CHILDREN" : ${child.hasChildren}
    }<#sep>, </#sep>
  </#list>
</#macro>
```